# Anylogic cannot be resolved or not a field

Tags: java, database, sorting, anylogic

So I am building a simulation in Anylogic of runway traffic flow based on a proven schedule. Each aircraft must be sorted once in the air to its correct flying space.

I have pseudo-coded the logic and even put it in a excel sheet to ensure logic works.

Currently in my SelectOutputOut I have

```
agent.mission.equals("3");
```

In my DB mission in an id linking to another table, therefore it is an int. This int let's me know what area to send it to. Every time I compile I get the error mission cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: Your code tells Java that `mission` lives within the agent. However, it sounds like it exists in the database itself, correct? You need to ensure you call `mission` from the right place

Comment: @Benjamin I have passed the db table through the agent, would this be incorrect practice?